# Prove that Vertex Cover is NP-Complete by reducing MaxCut to Vertex Cover

Tags: np-hardness, complexity, max-cut, vertex-cover

This is not the most straight forward reduction available on the internet since most people start from the fact that vertex cover is NP-complete and reduce a given vertex cover instance to MaxCut instance to show that MaxCut in NP-complete. I am looking for a gadget that goes the other way around. Given an instance of Maxcut, I want to reduce it to vertex cover. What is the gadget construction that achieves this?